# Search while typing, autocomplete input fields onclick

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm struggling trying to fill in 2 input boxes with an onclick event. The screenshot below shows the search window. The user types a name in the far right box to display matching results below (eg. test test). When "test test" is clicked the full name should appear on the (right box) without the ID and the ID (87) should appear in the (left box) without the name.

[image]

Here's the **fetch.php** file that queries the MySQL db:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    // $dataSource[] = $row;
        $client_id = $row['id'];
        $first_name = $row['first_name'];
        $last_name = $row['last_name'];
       // echo "$client_id" . " " . $first_name . " " . $last_name ."\n";

 echo '<div style="padding:3px">
 <button class="button" name="title" id="title" value="'.$client_id. ' '.$first_name.' '.$last_name.'" onclick="setText(this)">'.$first_name.' '.$last_name.'</button>
 </div>';
```

This is the index.php file:

```
<body>
<!-- search while typing  -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e)
    {
        $("#title").keyup(function()
        {
            $("#here").show();
            var x = $(this).val();
            
            
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type:'GET',
                    url:'fetch.php',
                    data: 'q='+x, /// start search only when first character is entered. q not empty.
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        $("#here").html(data); /// display results in <div id=here>
                        
                    }
                    ,
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Form:

```
   <input type="text" id="client_id" name="client_id" placeholder="ID"   onfocus="this.value=''" />
   <input type="text" id="status" name="status" placeholder="Status" autocomplete="off"  >
   <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Cliente"   autocomplete="off"  onfocus="this.value=''" />              


            <!-- auto fill  -->                
            <script>
            function setText(obj){
            var val = obj.value;
            console.log(val);

            function concat(){
            var x = document.getElementById('title').value = val;
            var y = document.getElementById('client_id').value = val;
            //var z = one + " " + two;
            document.getElementById("title").value = x;
            document.getElementById("client_id").value = y;
            }
            concat();
            }
            </script>      
                    <!-- display search results-->             
                    <div id="here" style="overflow: scroll;">
                    
                    </div>
```

Comment: Seems like you are missing the onclick event listener for div #here children to call your setText func. after you slam in the html then you probably need to loop the children and add the even listener for click.

Comment: Hey tstrand66. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.split(" ")` to split your value and then use index to get value from that array .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function setText(obj) {
  var val = obj.value.split(" "); //split
  document.getElementById("title").value = val[1] + "  " + val[2]; //firstname-lastname
  document.getElementById("client_id").value = val[0]; //id
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="client_id" name="client_id" placeholder="ID" onfocus="this.value=''" />
<input type="text" id="status" name="status" placeholder="Status" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Cliente" autocomplete="off" onfocus="this.value=''" />
<!--just for demo-->
<div id="here" style="overflow: scroll;">
  <div style="padding:3px">
    <button class="button" name="title" value="87 abc abc" onclick="setText(this)">abc abc</button>
  </div>
  <div style="padding:3px">
    <button class="button" name="title" value="82 abc2 abc2" onclick="setText(this)">abc2 abc2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```